# byte flipping data in C++ returns only zeroes

Tags: c++, gcc, endianness

I'm using the GCC compiler (codeblocks) on windows, and the data I'm getting is from a UNIX machine, so it's all in big-endian. I have to swap it to little endian before I can us it.  And I'll be dammed, but I can't get this to work.  Using

```
temp = ntohl(fileBuf[N*i+j]);
```

or

```
_byteswap_ulong(fileBuf[N*i+j]);
```

returns nothing but zeroes. Which I know for a fact is incorrect.

The incoming data is just a string of 32bit integers (elevation data for part of the USA).  Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT:  Pretty new here, I wasn't sure if the code would be useful

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE
int main()
{
    long int temp;
    int i,j;
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("fixed4.txt");
    const char *filePath = "input2";
    BYTE *fileBuf;
    FILE *file = NULL;
    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "rb"))==NULL)
       cout<< "File could not be opened successfully" << endl;
    else
        cout << "File Opened successfully" << endl;

    long fileSize = getFileSize(file);
    fileBuf = new BYTE[fileSize];
    //BYTE *flipped;
    //flipped = new BYTE[fileSize];

    fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 4, file);

    for (i=0; i<N; i+=1){
        for (j=0; j<N; j+=1){
            temp = _byteswap_ulong(fileBuf[N*i+j]);
            grid[i][j]=binaryToBase10(temp);

// more code here but it isn't important....
```

Comment: `ntohl` is pretty well tested, so it seems a fair guess that the problem is in the data you're supplying to it. Are you sure `filebuf[N*i+j]` is really the right data?

Comment: `printf("%x %x\n", fileBuf[N*i+j], ntohl(fileBuf[N*i+j])` and consider the results.

Comment: what type is fileBuf? and temp ?

Comment: Well you guys are right, the problem is in fileBuf.  This worked perfectly for 16bit swapping, but it isn't reading in the 32bit stuff correctly.  EG it is reading in all zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give us much to go on, so this is a crystal-ball guess.

The type of `fileBuf` is `char*` or `unsigned char*`. So, the value you pass to `ntohl` is the *single byte* at location (i,j), not the 32-bit int at (i,j).

One way (there are better ways) to solve that problem is this:

```
ntohl( *(uint32_t*)&fileBuf[N*i+j] )
```

Comment: That may also very well be undefined behaviour. It'd be better to read into a vector of integers right away.