# How does c++ interpret a binary number

Tags: c++, binary-data

I have a general question about binary numbers in c++.  I am reading in a binary file of 32-bit numbers, and then writing these numbers to a text file.  My question is, when I do

```
long int temp;
temp = ( fileBuf[N * 4 * i + 4 * j + 0] << 24 |
         fileBuf[N * 4 * i + 4 * j + 1] << 16 |
         fileBuf[N * 4 * i + 4 * j + 2] << 8  | 
         fileBuf[N * 4 * i + 4 * j + 3] << 0  );
myfile1 << temp << "\t";
```

does c++ understand that I want it to reinterpret the binary as a decimal number?

Comment: C++ doesn’t know either about binary nor about decimal numbers, except when reading them from an input stream or writing to an output stream (`iostream`).

Comment: fileBuf reads in individual bytes, type BYTE.

Comment: Oh hey, its the rest of the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527763/byte-flipping-data-in-c-returns-only-zeroes

Comment: Yeah, I got the rest of it figured out, this was just a check on my part.  All my numbers look good, I just wanted to check every last thing before I send this off to another group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret this question as "Will this do what I want it to?" then the answer is **yes**, as long as what you want it to do is read a 32 bit, big endian integer out of a buffer (presumably loaded from a file) at offset `4 * N * i + 4 * j`.

Assuming of course that fileBuf is declared as a character or unsigned character type.  It would behave differently if it were, for example, an array of shorts.  You'd end up with a mutilated representation of a 64 bit quantity.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*All* numbers inside of a C++ `int` variable are binary. The conversion to or from decimal occurs as the number is read or written, or as the compiler converts it from a constant into code.

Answer (score 0):

No. In fact, the number isn't converted to decimal until you print it out in the very last line.